# (r) Run a function iteratively on a matrix with a different row removed each time i.e. function(matrix - row 1), function(matrix - row 2) etc

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix

Apologies if this has been dealt with before, I'm somewhat of a noob and can't seem to see anything similar.

I want to run a function on a matrix of data, but I want to run the function multiple times, each time with a different row of my matrix removed i.e. first with row 1 removed, then with row 2 removed (but with row 1 present), then with row 3 removed (but with row 1 and row 2 present) etc.

**Example**

Lets say I have a matrix with ten rows and ten columns:

```
matrix <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10)
row.names(matrix) <- c(1:10)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1     1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
2     2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
3     3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
4     4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
5     5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
6     6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
7     7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
8     8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
9     9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
10   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

And lets say I want to take the sum of the matrix 10 times, each time with a different row removed.

I can do this manually via:

```
sum(matrix[-1,])
sum(matrix[-2,])
sum(matrix[-3,])
sum(matrix[-4,])
etc
```

But this is slow (my actual matrix has nearly 10,000 rows).

I'm trying to write a for loop to do this in one go, but after a couple of hours of banging my head against a brick wall, I'm getting nowhere.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `sapply` to loop through the sequence of rows, then get the `sum` of the 'matrix' after removing the row index

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(matrix)), function(i) sum(matrix[-i,]))
#[1] 4590 4580 4570 4560 4550 4540 4530 4520 4510 4500
```

---

Or we can do this in a vectorized way by subtracting the `sum` of 'matrix' with the `rowSums` of 'matrix'

```
unname(sum(matrix) - rowSums(matrix))
#[1] 4590 4580 4570 4560 4550 4540 4530 4520 4510 4500
```